# jquery responsive wordpress slider height change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a premium wordpress theme which came with a built in full page slider. It integrates nicely into my website but it displays full page and the information underneath is being lost. The slider is responsive to the window size, I'd like it to be only 60%. Please can someone help:

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";
 $.fn.maximage = function (settings, helperSettings) {

var config;

if (typeof settings == 'object' || settings === undefined) config = $.extend( $.fn.maximage.defaults, settings || {} );
if (typeof settings == 'string') config = $.fn.maximage.defaults;

/*jslint browser: true*/
$.Body = $('body');
$.Window = $(window);
$.Scroll = $('html, body');
$.Events = {
  RESIZE: 'resize'
};

this.each(function() {
  var $self = $(this),
  preload_count = 0,
  imageCache = [];

  /* --------------------- */

  // @Modern

  /*
  MODERN BROWSER NOTES:
  Modern browsers have CSS3 background-size option so we setup the DOM to be the following structure for cycle plugin:
  div = cycle
  div = slide with background-size:cover
  div = slide with background-size:cover
  etc.
  */

  var Modern = {
    setup: function(){
      if($.Slides.length > 0){
        // Setup images
        for(var i in $.Slides) {
          // Set our image
          var $img = $.Slides[i];

          // Create a div with a background image so we can use CSS3's position cover (for modern browsers)
          $self.append('<div class="mc-image ' + $img.theclass + '" title="' + $img.alt + '" style="background-image:url(\'' + $img.url + '\');' + $img.style + '" data-href="'+ $img.datahref +'">'+ $img.content +'</div>');
        }

        // Begin our preload process (increments itself after load)
        Modern.preload(0);

        // If using Cycle, this resets the height and width of each div to always fill the window; otherwise can be done with CSS
        Modern.resize();
      }
    },
    preload: function(n){
      // Preload all of the images but never show them, just use their completion so we know that they are done
      //        and so that the browser can cache them / fade them in smoothly

      // Create new image object
      var $img = $('<img/>');
      $img.load(function() {
        // Once the first image has completed loading, start the slideshow, etc.
        if(preload_count==0) {
          // Only start cycle after first image has loaded
          Cycle.setup();

          // Run user defined onFirstImageLoaded() function
          config.onFirstImageLoaded();
        }

        // preload_count starts with 0, $.Slides.length starts with 1
        if(preload_count==($.Slides.length-1)) {
          // If we have just loaded the final image, run the user defined function onImagesLoaded()
          config.onImagesLoaded( $self );
        }else{
          // Increment the counter
          preload_count++;

          // Load the next image
          Modern.preload(preload_count);
        }
      });

      // Set the src... this triggers begin of load
      $img[0].src = $.Slides[n].url;

      // Push to external array to avoid cleanup by aggressive garbage collectors
      imageCache.push($img[0]);
    },
    resize: function(){
      // Cycle sets the height of each slide so when we resize our browser window this becomes a problem.
      //  - the cycle option 'slideResize' has to be set to false otherwise it will trump our resize
      $.Window
      .bind($.Events.RESIZE,
        function(){
          // Remove scrollbars so we can take propper measurements
          $.Scroll.addClass('mc-hide-scrolls');

          // Set vars so we don't have to constantly check it
          $.Window
          .data('h', Utils.sizes().h)
          .data('w', Utils.sizes().w);

          // Set container and slides height and width to match the window size
          $self
          .height($.Window.data('h')).width($.Window.data('w'))
          .children()
          .height($.Window.data('h')).width($.Window.data('w'));

          // This is special noise for cycle (cycle has separate height and width for each slide)
          $self.children().each(function(){
            this.cycleH = $.Window.data('h');
            this.cycleW = $.Window.data('w');
          });

          // Put the scrollbars back to how they were
          $($.Scroll).removeClass('mc-hide-scrolls');
        });
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance. James

Comment: Probably a simple css change would do the trick. If you post a link to your page (or any page using this slider), we could probably help in a few mins. *Strategy would be to examine page in Chrome Dev Tools (F12), find slider container, and experiment with css.* Give that a try yourself, also.

Comment: Hi gibberish. I've tried amending the container within the CSS in Chrome as you suggest but because the script is constantly monitoring page height it changes all the time. I've managed this with different sliders before but I seem to be going around in circles with this one

Comment: Here is the page in question: http://www.veloclubrutland.co.uk/

Comment: which slider plugin you are using?

Comment: This is the one that was bundled with the theme. There are no options in the theme to adjust the height as suggested. http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the themes are very customizable on the admin panel. So, you should check it out before you changing it by hand.

If you dont find for customization on the admin panel (and on the theme developer page), as you may be know, when the themes are responsive they are using some framework like bootstrap, foundation, whatever. And then, the slider have to have a css class like "large-12", it should be modified to change its size, for example "large-8", then the slider size will be 8/12.

I hope it help you!